# How to publish and subscribe float/double type value on a topic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, callback function used for the subscriber in the ROS tutorial are all string type, and callback functions are void type.

However, I need to use the subscribed values (e.g. velocities) for other purposes. Is there a way to pass and receive non-string type messages?

Thanks.

---

How do you modify the callback function prototype below?

`void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66279/how-to-publish-and-subscribe-float/double-type-value-on-a-topic?/) by [Bholms](https://answers.ros.org/users/5097/bholms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could definitely decompose the sting messages with regular expressions.

Or, you could use a different message data type that has a float container.

Or, you could write your own message type.

Or, you could use the float message.

http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/ChannelFloat32.html

---

Have you done the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials)? If not, I recommend you do so. ROS is a complicated system, and you need to really grasp the concepts before you attempt coding. It is very important you understand what a [Message](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Messages) is, and how to use them.

However, to answer your question, it depends on how you are modifying it. For the float message, you will need to add to the top of your code the following line.

```
#include <sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32>
```

Now, you can change the function to read

```
void floatCallback(const sensor_msgs::ChannelFloat32::ConstPtr& float_msg)
```

and that should work.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-07-15**:
Hmm... `sensor_msgs/ChannelFloat32.msg` isn't "the float message", `std_msgs/Float32` (or `Float64`) is. And for velocities, `geometry_msgs/Twist` is the standard.